# Select datetimepicker date as per mysql table column date (c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, datetimepicker

I have two Windows forms. One is `Insert new member` and other one is `Edit member`.

When inserting a new member, I can select the `Membership Date`. I would like to get the selected `Membership Date` into the `Edit member` form, where I have a `datetimepicker`.

Example: I create a new member with an ID `A-15` and their membership date of `15/05/2013`. When I want to edit this member, I will type the `Membership ID` into the `Edit member` form and run the program. This will load all details into textboxes and the `Membership Date` into the `datetimepicker`.

I am having trouble with the `datetimepicker`. How do I select the date and display it in  the `datetimepicker` from the information in the `MySQL` table?

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[DONORINFO] ( [MEMBERSHIP_NO] [VARCHAR](10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[NAME_STATE] [VARCHAR](10) NULL, [FULL_NAME] [VARCHAR](100) NULL, [STREET_NO] [VARCHAR]
(50) NULL, [STREET] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL, [CITY] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL, [TEL] [VARCHAR]
(50) NULL, [EMAIL] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL, [DIOCESE] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL, [CUS_TYPE]
[VARCHAR] (50) NULL, [MEMBERSHIP_DATE] [DATE], );
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: to load all data to Edit Member, I have used a data table. Problem is how to get date in data table into datetimepicker. How to pasre into date.

Comment: please update question with how you retrieve data from database and which column you want to get membership date and what is the data type you saved in mysql

Comment: CREATE TABLE [DBO].[DONORINFO]
(
[MEMBERSHIP_NO] [VARCHAR](10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[NAME_STATE] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[FULL_NAME] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
[STREET_NO] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
[STREET] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
[CITY] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
[TEL] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
[EMAIL] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
[DIOCESE] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
[CUS_TYPE] [VARCHAR] (50) NULL,
[MEMBERSHIP_DATE] [DATE],
);
 this is my table template. I have used data table to retrieve and store data from sql table.

Comment: @amilajayashanka Edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get membership [date value from the `datatable`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow-field) and set it as selected date of `datetimepicker`

```
DateTime membershipdate = YourDataTable.Row[0].Field<DateTime>("MEMBERSHIP_DATE");
datetimepicker.Value= membershipdate;
```

Comment: datetimepicker.SelectedDate = membershipdate.Value; In here "SelectedDate" option cannot find. Im using vs8 and is there any alternate option

Comment: still cant find that "selectedDate" option

Comment: @amila it should be `Value`